# What is the correct way to access a third party package from my custom module?

Tags: javascript

If `client.js` contains:

```js
// https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator
import validator from 'validator';

// my own module
import input_validator from './my_modules/input_validator';

// call the function exported from my module
input_validator(params);
```

And `/my_modules/input_validator.js` contains:

```js
const input_validator = (params) => {

    // do things and call the 'validator' package
    var result = validator.equals(param1, param2);
}

module.exports = input_validator;
```

I am getting this error when calling `input_validator(params)` from `client.js`:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: validator is not defined
```

It seems I have wrongly assumed that because the package `validator` is imported into `client.js`, it should be available to `/my_modules/input_validator` which is imported "later".

**Question**

What is the correct way to organise my imports so that the package `validator` is available within `/my_modules/input_validator.js`?

**Possible Solution**

The following seems to work but I just want to confirm it is the correct way to do it:

`/my_modules/input_validator.js`:

```js
// add the package import directly to my module 
import validator from 'validator';

// leave the rest as is  

const input_validator = (params) => {

    // do things and call the 'validator' package
    var result = validator.equals(param1, param2);
}

module.exports = input_validator;
```

`client.js`:

```js
// remove import from this file
// import validator from 'validator';

// leave the rest as is 

// my own module
import input_validator from './my_modules/input_validator';

// call the function exported from my module
input_validator(params);
```

Comment: In short, your assumption is correct. Modules must be imported into each file in which their exports are used.

Comment: Thank you, what would happen if I wanted to use a package's functionality in *both* a custom module of my own *and* the main `client.js` file?   Would I need to import it into both files (ie the custom module and `client.js`)?  And, if so, does that result is doubling the size of the imported code (as it is imported twice) - or does it somehow intelligently know that both imports refer to the same piece of code, and therefore it should only technically be imported into the file once?